# What happened to Poe?

Tags: record-labels, poe

[Poe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe_(singer)) (Ann Danielewski) had a rising music career in the late 1990s, but then she completely vanished from the public eye. I’ve heard a variety of stories about her disappearance, ranging from corporate mergers to mismanagement to financial and legal trouble. Many stories claim that she was *not allowed* to record or perform music. How is that possible, and what actually happened?

Comment: This gives an overview of wat happened: http://www.agentassociation.com/media/asset/SDOC0365.pdf

Comment: Take a listen to her collaboration with Conjure one called center of the sun....it's amazing!

Answer (score 8):

As you stated in the question itself its due to the merger of
recording company and legal fights.

> - Poe's three album deal is lost in Atlantic/AOL Time Warner merger. In November 2000, Atlantic/AOL Time Warner first chose to drop the
>   Modern/FEI, and as a result were contractually obligated to pay
>   Modern/FEI an undisclosed amount of money, and effectively release
>   themselves from any further fiduciary responsibilities to Modern/ FEI
>   and/or Poe.
> - Modern/FEI's agreed to give Atlantic a two-year grace period during which Modern/FEI agreed not to do anything commercially with any of
>   Poe's master recordings, enabling Atlantic to sell off their stock of
>   already produced copies of "Haunted." As a result, "Haunted" received
>   no further promotional support and the album faded from the market
>   place.
> - In 2004, Modern/ FEI sold the Poe Masters for "Hello" and "Haunted" to Sheridan Square Music who merged in 2005 with V2 Records, which
>   cataloged the Poe masters under a sub-label called Indie Blue. Indie
>   Blue and Sheridan Square Music were acquired by E-One Music in 2009.
> - Though Modern/ FEI kept ownership of Poe’s masters until 2004, in 2001 as “Haunted” was climbing the charts, the label sold its interest
>   in Poe as an artist and in Poe’s future recordings, in a questionable
>   deal to wealthy oil executive and author Robert M. Edsel who bought
>   her contract and kept Poe tied up in court, unable to release new
>   music or perform professionally for nearly a decade. What music Poe
>   did release during that time was generally done under the pseudonym
>   “Jane.”
>
> The contract eventually ended after 10 years of legal wrangling, when
> The Labor Commission of California ruled in favor of Poe. New York
> Post writer, Miriam Katz, quoted Poe in her 2011 article, “A Decade of
> Silence,” about Poe’s ten-year legal battles, “My entire life was
> suddenly under the control of a very powerful man whom I didn’t know,
> and who didn’t [seem to] mean well. It was a horror story from which I
> am just beginning to recover.
>
> (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe_%28singer%29#Poe.27s_three_album_deal_is_lost_in_Atlantic.2FAOL_Time_Warner_merger))

This all conditions made her 10 years of disappearance and even after it she doesn't have came up with any grand thing yet. On September 12, 2012, Poe posted a one-minute song and video on a new mobile platform called PTCH; however, no announcement was made about an official release date.

Comment: I was hoping to get some information that wasn't already in the Wikipedia article linked from the question. Basically I don't get how this results in a musician being unable to perform for *over ten years.*

Comment: @BraddSzonye if singer has contracted signed with a company stating that she can't perform outside the company then she can't without breaking contract which is not that easy and even she performed under the pseudonym “Jane” under the hood of Robert.

Comment: Sadly, this not an uncommon story in the music business, although having it last ten full years is unusual. Over the years many recording artists under contract have found themselves contractually prohibited from releasing and selling, or in many cases even *recording* any new music. The nature of the artist signing a contract with a record label or music publishing company is that of "indentured servitude" under California and USA law.